# Is there any altitude below which an unlicensed pilot can fly over private property?

Tags: faa-regulations

First: this is a hypothetical question; I am not going to fly a plane anywhere at any altitude unless/until I am properly trained and licensed.

Suppose I am not a licensed pilot, but I own a large area of land and a Cessna 172. Is there any altitude below which I could legally fly the plane over my own land?

Comment: If you like rules and restrictions then aviation is for you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**No**; you cannot legally cause an aircraft to “move under its own power for the purpose of flight” (14 CFR 1.1, Flight Time) without some sort of license unless it falls under an exemption, which your Cessna 172 does not.

Arguably, you would be breaking the law as soon as you started the engine, before you even left the ground.

However, there is a huge exemption for ultralight aircraft.  The idea is that they’re so small and slow that you’re unlikely to do serious damage or injury to anyone other than yourself.  (The FAA exists to protect the general public, not pilots.)  But you’d still be wise to get some training for your own sake.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139610/discussion-on-answer-by-stephens-is-there-any-altitude-below-which-an-unlicensed).

Answer (score 3):

The correct answer is that **federal regulations prohibit an unlicensed pilot from flying a certified aircraft in US airspace *under FAA jurisdiction***.  Given that Class G airspace extends to the surface, that means pretty much anywhere in CONUS.

However, there are a few things worth considering that might make such an act defensible...

Consider for a minute that if you are reading this in the United States then as soon as you step outside your abode you probably protrude into Class G airspace.  Class G is uncontrolled by ATC of course, but otherwise does the FAA exercise any authority over you for the fact that you are now in airspace that they have jurisdiction over?  Of course not, they only care about the airspace airplanes commonly operate in, i.e. "navigable" airspace of the National Airspace System (NAS), not the private, personal airspace just above your backyard.  But where is the altitude cutoff that delineates private airspace from the NAS?

I couldn't find a consistent answer to this, but there are other regulations and legal precedents that can help us understand a bit more about what is considered navigable airspace for the purpose of FAA jurisdiction.

[This article provides a useful perspective.](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2013/07/photographer-george-steinmetz-arrest-how-much-airspace-do-you-own.html#:%7E:text=While%20the%20Supreme%20Court%20hasn,500%20feet%20above%20the%20ground.)  It states:

> Before the advent of air travel, landowners owned an infinitely tall
> column of air rising above their plot. (The Latin doctrine was Cujus
> est solum ejus usque ad coelum, or “whose is the soil, his it is up to
> the sky.”) In 1946 the Supreme Court acknowledged that the air had
> become a “public highway,” but **a landowner still had dominion** over “at
> least as much of the space above the ground as he can occupy or use in
> connection with the land.” In that case the court held that a plane
> flying just 83 feet in the air—the commotion was literally scaring the
> plaintiff’s chickens to death—represented an invasion of property. The
> justices declined to precisely define the height at which ownership
> rights end.

Apparently drawing a parallel with the altitude restriction in uncongested areas, it goes on to say:

> Today, the federal government considers the area above 500 feet to be
> navigable airspace in uncongested areas. While the Supreme Court
> hasn’t explicitly accepted that as the upper limit of property
> ownership, it’s a useful guideline in trespass cases. Therefore,
> unless you own some very tall buildings, **your private airspace**
> probably ends somewhere between 80 and 500 feet above the ground.

Another useful perspective can be gleaned from the FAA restriction on recreational drone flying, whose maximum altitude is capped at 400’ AGL to deconflict with aircraft operating within the NAS.  There may be additional examples of regulations on antenna heights, max height for flying kites, etc, that can give a more complete picture, but I will stop there.

While it would be unwise to challenge this, a skilled lawyer arguing before a sympathetic jury could probably keep you out of hot water if you were to fly at 400' AGL or below in the private airspace over your own personal land.

Comment: One should probably add that "altitude is your friend" in terms of flight safety; a new pilot staying below 500 feet AGL is all sorts of bad idea -- and one who had his license pulled likely wouldn't stand up well in court...

Comment: @ZeissIkon, totally agree on the safety of flight aspect, I infer that it would be a bad idea in a couple places already.  Kind of thought it was a no brainer.  Regarding enforcement actions, there is no license to pull...

Comment: I was referring to a *formerly* licensed, as opposed to never-licensed individual.